# How do I show a popup interstitial ad in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to show an interstitial popup ad on my app after the player dies. I have a function for it in the ViewController but I don't know how to use it in GameScene. I have the following code in the View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

protocol AdMobInterstitialDelegate{
    func createInterstitialAd()
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, AdMobInterstitialDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

let scene = GameScene()

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

@IBOutlet weak var adbanner: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-1279952988973855/9087084328")
    let request = GADRequest()
    // Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
    // an ad request is made.
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
    interstitial.load(request)

    //self.createInterstitialAd()


    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

    }
}

func createInterstitialAd(){
    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}
```

and I have the following code in my GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var adDelegate: AdMobInterstitialDelegate?

    func createGameOver(){ 
    self.adDelegate?.createInterstitialAd()
}
```

I don't know what exactly is going wrong, I have a feeling I am putting the createInterstitialAd() function incorrectly in the protocol, but I am really not sure. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The scene you are creating is an SKScene, not your subclassed GameScene.

Change:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
```

To:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
```

Also You are not setting the delegate reference adDelegate so it remains nil and the call to createInterstitialAd will never happen due to the conditional unwrapping (i.e. the ?).

After:

```
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

Add:

```
scene.adDelegate = self
```

(Also, you do not need the 'self.' in:

```
self.adDelegate?.createInterstitialAd()
```

but that won't cause problems, it is just not necessary.)

Comment: When I do this I get an error that says "Value of type "SKScene" has no member "adDelegate". Thanks

Comment: @PranavSharan Ah, there is another problem - see my edited answer.

Comment: @PranavSharan Also your code shown never calls createGameOver - is that called from somewhere else?